# Struct doesn't have a field error message in c

Tags: c, struct, typedef, clion

I'm trying to write a binary search tree, however my Clion IDE is giving me this error in various places: `Struct TreeNode doesn't have a field 'balance'`.
I chose 'balance' as an example, but this happens to every field in the struct.
My entire header file is as follows:

```
#define CARD_SIZE 15

typedef struct TreeNode *node_ptr;

typedef struct TreeNode{
    char card[CARD_SIZE];
    int balance;
    node_ptr left;
    node_ptr right;
    node_ptr parent;
}Node;
```

And an example where the error occurs is:

```
bool updateSearch(int balance, char *card) {
    node_ptr node = searchNode(card,tree.root);
    if(node){
        node->balance += balance; //Right here
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

What might be causing this problem?

Comment: Are you sure that the `node_ptr` in the second snippet is the same as the one in the first? 'node_ptr' is very generic, and prone to be redefined.

Comment: @PaulFloyd Yes, that's the only `node_ptr` definition.

Comment: I tried to reproduce. (I had to add some things to make it an [mcve] in C.) Finally, I got it until link errors. Hence, no **compiling issue** anymore... Here the link: [**ideone**](https://ideone.com/iUcgCK)

Comment: I was not really sure about that but gcc 6.3 proved me: `bool`, `true`, and `false` are not C. (not by standard) Do you compile your C code  with a C++ compiler?

Comment: @PaulR yes no semicolon or anything. I've updated my post with my whole header file. The first error (apart from never used warnings) is the error in the post.

Comment: Does the code compile correctly? If so, the error is limited to CLion.

Comment: @Scheff I'm new to Clion and having some difficulties due to its complexity, but i'm using its default compiler in a C project. Also i've included `#include <stdbool.h>`  since boolean values are not C standard

Comment: I think you need to prune this down to a [mcve], as the problem most likely lies somewhere other than what you're not showing us.

Comment: OK. Didn't know about `stdbool.h` - you hadn't mentioned this in your code sample. You could take my source on ideone, add the missing function, and try this on your side. If the issue still persists, you might edit your question and use it as MCVE.

Comment: `stdbool.h` is C99 though the compiler may accept it with C90

Comment: And does this help https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206606835-Unable-to-use-c99-mode to put CLion in C99 or C11 mode? [I have no experience with CLion]

Comment: @PaulFloyd Tried the same code in another ide (codeblocks) and apart from the same unused functions warning it produced no error. So why is Clion pointing out an error that "doesn't exist"? Is my strutc definition incorrect?

Comment: Can you copy the error that you are getting (I'm still not clear whether it is a CLion code analysis error https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/code-analysis.html or a build error)?

Comment: @PaulFloyd Oh i see. It's definitely a code analysis error. It builds fine, and following the link you provided it does show as a code analysis error rather then a build error.

Comment: Speculation: since `node_ptr` is declared before `TreePtr`, all the compiler sees at that time is that it points to some unknown kind of `struct`, which might not ever be defined in the same translation unit. So perhaps the analyzer isn’t able to unify it with the definition that follows, and that’s why it doesn’t know what any of the fields are. Does changing `node_ptr` to `struct TreeNode*` inside the `struct` definition and moving the declaration of `node_ptr` after it eliminate the error?

Comment: @Davislor Yes it did, but it just seems wrong to `typedef` a pointer to the structure you're defining inside the structure definition. At least is something i have never seem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments, we seem to have diagnosed the problem, and @joneleam confirmed that the workaround works.

This was not a compilation error, but a limitation of the static analyzer.  In the code snippet, the definition of `node_ptr` as `struct TreeNode*` precedes the definition of `struct TreeNode`.  So, when the compiler sees that declaration, all it knows is that `TreeNode` is some kind of `struct`, which might not even necessarily be defined in the same translation unit.  When it does see the definition of `struct TreeNode` immediately after, it fails to unify this with the definition of `node_ptr` as `struct TreeNode*`.  Therefore, it does not know what the `node_ptr` members of a `struct TreeNode` point to, even though it points to another `TreeNode`!

The workaround is to refactor as:

```
#define CARD_SIZE 15

typedef struct TreeNode{
    char card[CARD_SIZE];
    int balance;
    struct TreeNode* left;
    struct TreeNode* right;
    struct TreeNode* parent;
}Node;

typedef struct TreeNode *node_ptr;
```

You *could* also, technically, `#define NODE_PTR struct TreeNode*`, if writing it out uglifies the code too much for you, but that’s even more of a code smell to me.  Unless the devs add support for correct code such as yours, or there’s a better workaround, it’s up to you what trade-off you want to make.

Comment: The code is perfectly valid C.  `typedef struct TreeNode *node_ptr;` declares `struct TreeNode` as an incomplete type.  The following declaration makes it a complete type. But apparently Clion's static analyzer doesn't recognize that the second declaration completes the type declared in the first declaration. I'd call this a bug, not just a limitation, and I suggest reporting it.

Comment: @KeithThompson Agreed that it is “correct code” (as I said in my answer). Interesting philosophical question whether to call this a “bug.” After all, Alan Turing proved there will always be *some* perfectly-valid program in any Turing-complete language that will confound any given static analyzer. But I agree that this is something the CLion devs ought to fix. The analyzer should be able to unify the forward reference to `struct TreeNode` and its use inside the `struct` block with the complete type, just as the compiler does.

Comment: I'm not sure what Turing has to do with this. It's just a matter of correctly processing C source code. Compilers are required to do it; a third-party analyzer should be required to do it too. There are things a static analyzer can't always determine (such as whether a program halts), but correctness of the code according to the language rules isn't one of them.

Comment: @KeithThompson This definitely falls into the category of things a static analyzer can and should be able to figure out, yes.